# How to display an active message only after the account was inactive in java program?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project based on challenge 9 of chapter 10 from the book Starting out with java from control structures through data structures. The idea is to create a BankAccount class and a SavingsAccount class that extends BankAccount. I have a lot done but one of the parts where I am stuck is, when the account balance drops under $25 a message of account being inactive is displayed, once under $25 if you make a deposit to make your balance $25 or more, a message of account active is displayed, I got the inactive to work but I cannot get the active message because it has to be inactive until the balance drops, that message only shows after the account came back from being active, I tried an if statement similar to the one I used if account goes under 25 but it was showing that message everytime the balance is above 25 and I need to display only after the account came back from being inactive. Any ideas would be appreciated, here is my code:

```
///BankDemo class
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankDemo {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        float startingBalance;
        float interestRate;
        String userInput;
                
        System.out.print("Enter beginning balance :$");
        startingBalance = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate(whole number) :%");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        float bal = startingBalance;
        float rate = interestRate;
        
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(startingBalance, interestRate);
        SavingsAccount sv = new SavingsAccount(bal, rate);
        
        while(startingBalance > -1) {
            System.out.println("Enter D for deposit" + "\nEnter W to Withdraw" + "\nEnter B for Balance" + 
                                "\nEnter M for Monthly Process" + "\nEnter E to Exit");
            userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            
            if("d".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.deposit();
            } else if("w".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.withdraw();
            } else if("b".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.totalBalance();
            } else if("m".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.monthlyProcess();
            } else {
                System.out.print("Error, option not valid\n");
            }
        }
    }

}
///BankAccount class
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankAccount {
    protected float balance;
    protected float numDeposits;
    protected float numWithdrawals;
    protected float annualRate;
    protected float monthlyServCharg;
    float charge = 1;
    
    public BankAccount(float startingBalance, float interestRate) {
        balance = startingBalance;
        annualRate = interestRate /= 100.0;
    }
    public void deposit() {
        float valueD;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to deposit :$");
        valueD = keyboard.nextFloat();
        if(valueD < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance += valueD;
        numDeposits++;
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        float valueW;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to withdraw :$");
        valueW = keyboard.nextFloat();
        if(valueW < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance -= valueW;
        numWithdrawals++;
        if(balance < 25) {
            System.out.print("Your balance is less than minimum balance. Your account is now INACTIVE\n");
        }
        if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
            balance --;
            System.out.print("You have exceeded monthly limit of withdrawals. Fee of $1 charged\n");
        }
    }
    public void totalBalance() {
        System.out.printf("Your Balance is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    public void calcInterest() {
        float monRate = annualRate / 12;
        float monInt = balance * monRate;
        balance += monInt;
    }
    public void monthlyProcess() {
        calcInterest();
        balance -= monthlyServCharg;
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        monthlyServCharg = 0;
        System.out.printf("Your Balance after Monthly process is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    
    public void exit() {
        totalBalance();
        System.out.print("\nThank you. Bye");
    }
}
///SavingsAccount class
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    private boolean active;
    
    public SavingsAccount(float bal, float rate) {
        super(bal, rate);
        if(bal < 25)
            active = false;
        else
            active = true;
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        if(active)
            super.withdraw();
    }
    public void deposit(float amount) {
        if(!active) {
            if(amount + balance < 25)
                return;
        }
        super.deposit();
    }
    public void withdrawals() {
        if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
            monthlyServCharg += numWithdrawals - 4;
        }
        if(balance < 25)
            active = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you add to the balance, check if the balance is < 25 and if balance + deposit > 25. Then you can show the message. Then increase the real balance.

Comment: @NomadMaker I tried that but wherever I locate it shows the message every time the balance + deposit > 25, I only need it to show once, only when the account is back from inactive, after that if the balance stays above 25 it should not be displaying it

Comment: That's why you have to do the check before you actually increase the balance.

Comment: @NomadMaker Thanks for your time to assist me, unfortunately Im not able to make it work, if not much to ask, would you mind writing how would you put it in the code?

Comment: Add an `active` flag and set it to `false` when the account goes inactive.  Use what @NomadMaker said but include the `!active` before hand.  Once the account goes Active you will stop displaying it until it goes inactive again. OH, you have one in `SavingsAccount`, just move the message there.